# How to use SpannableString in Kotlin MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-databinding

I'm kinda stack with this scenario actually, Since I need to span some characters in my string, but still gives me a plain text. Do you guys have any suggestion here how to use `SpannableString` not directly using in `TextView` but instead assigning this to the `String` object and will be use later on the `TextView`? It is obvious it will work inside the activity and fragment. but I'm working on the outside of the context since I'm using a shared component.

example:

I have here a ui factory.

```
fun DataDto.spanSomeText(resource: Resources): SpannableStringBuilder {
 val stringBuilder = SpannableStringBuilder()
 val spannedText = SpannableString(resource.getString(R.string.text_label)).apply {
  setSpan(**implementation**)
 }
 return stringBuilder
        .append(resource.getString(spannedText))
        .append(resource.getString(dataDtoObject, formatString))
}
```

then I have a data class will handle this objects from this dto.

```
// this is from another package that is shared component
DataClassToUi(
 textfield: @RawValue Any?
) {
 fun getString(context): CharSequence? = when(textfield) {
  is OtherStringHander -> textfield.cleanString(context)
  is SpannableStringBuilder,
  is SpannableString -> textfield as CharSequence
  else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("data type is not string")
 }
}

fun DataDto.toDetails(resource: Resources) = DataClassToUi(
 textfield = data.spanSomeText(resource)
)
```

and on the xml

```
<layout>
 <data>
  <variable
    name="data"
    type="path.DataClassToUi" />
 </data>
 <TextView>
  android:text="@{data.getString(context)}"
 </TextView>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `String` *is* just plain text, it's just a bunch of characters, so when you call `toString` you're basically stripping out all your extra data about the spans etc

`String` implements `CharSequence`, which is a more general text representation that *can* hold all that extra data - and a `SpannableStringBuilder` itself is a `CharSequence`. So you can use it directly in a `TextView` with its `setText(charSequence)` method, or you can store it in a `CharSequence` variable to be passed around your app.

So it'll probably work if you just make `fun DataDto.spanSomeText` return a `CharSequence` instead of a `String`, and pass back `stringBuilder` itself instead of calling `toString` on it. `DataClassToUi.textField` will have to be a `CharSequence` too though - since `String`s *are* `CharSequence`s anything that was already using `String`s should be ok, but you might have to add some `toString` calls, and you won't be able to serialise the `CharSequence` as easily (since it's an interface, it could be any kind of object, can't just throw it in a `SharedPreferences` or whatever like you can with a `String`)